# git config --global core.filemode false does not work with git diff

Tags: git

I have set

```
 git config --global core.filemode false
```

And checked that my config is ok with `git config -l`

```
...
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.autocrlf=false
...
```

But when I type `git diff foo` I get this:

```
diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
diff --git a/config.ini b/config.ini
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
...
```

I imported a remote repository inside mine with:

```
git remote add foo //192.168.1.42/foo/
git pull foo master
git checkout -b foo foo/master
git diff master
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Were you able to make it work? The answer below has no effect in my case

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure you don't have multiple entries of that setting and set it locally instead of globally:

```
git config --global --unset-all core.filemode
git config --unset-all core.filemode
git config core.filemode false
```

Comment: @nowox can you try a `git reset -- .gitignore`? And `git add -- .gitignore` again?

Comment: my `git status` gives `On branch foo\n nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: @nowox strange, what version of Git are you using? Do you see the same with Git 2.4.2 (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: Same behavior between 2.1.4 and 2.4.0

Comment: I don't have it installed yet

Comment: @nowox sure: unzip it anywhere you want, add it to your path and done.

Comment: @DavidT It makes sure no other configuration exists elsewhere and the only the local config prevails.

Comment: @IulianT OK, could you describe your context in a separate question? (OS, git version, command typed, expected result vs. what you actually get).

Comment: oddly, second line did it for me, while adding 3 line makes mode message appear again